# convert linspace array to 1d array on python

Tags: python, arrays

I'm using linspace to generate an array of 100 elements, the result's shape is (100,) but I want to obtain an array with the following shape (100, 1). How can I do it? I tried reshape but it does not give the required result. Here is an exmaple :

```
import numpy as np
om1 = np.linspace(-50, 50, 100);
om = np.random.randn(100,1);
print(shape(om1))
print(shape(om))
```

Output :

```
>>> (100, )
(100, 1)
```

Comment: Your code isn't valid python, there is no `shape` function. Did you mean `om1.shape`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't the numpy array have a `reshape` method?  https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.reshape.html#numpy.ndarray.reshape

```py
om1 = np.linspace(-50, 50, 100).reshape( (100, 1) )
```

Comment: That works for me ! Thanks @xtofl ! I was using reshape in the wrong way ig...

Comment: You could say that.  Since I have made the same mistake, I dare to say that `np.array.reshape` has been given the wrong name.  Had it been `np.array.reshaped`, many frustrating developer-hours would have been saved.

Comment: No, I just typed `om=reshape(len(om),1)` instead of `om=om.reshape(len(om),1)` I didn't pay attention sorry!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`reshape`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) to add the missing dimension without knowing the length of your array

```
om1.reshape(-1,1)
```

With `-1` as one dimension the length of that dimension is inferred.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelSzczesny ! That's a useful information!